# Border around HTML Page Not Working

Tags: html, css, border

I have looked around for a few different solutions on Google and tried them out, but I still cannot seem to get my page border to work.

I tried creating another div container to contain everything on the page, then I had the div with the four div circles on the inside, but that did not work when I added the border.
So, I took the outer div away and just left the one div with the four div circles inside.

Finally (what is below), I tried adding the border to the body, but it still does not put the border around the entire page.

I have a feeling that the problem might have to do with height and width values, but I have played with those as well and could not get the desires results.

Thanks for any advice

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background: white;
                border: 1px solid #ff0000;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .circle {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
                -moz-border-radius: 50px;
                border-radius: 50px;
                text-align: center;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .container {
                text-align: center;
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            Welcome to My Website!
            <br>
            <br>
        </center>
        <div class = "container">
            <div class= "circle" style = "background-color:red">About</div>
            <div class= "circle"style = "background-color:orange">Homework</div>
            <div class= "circle"style = "background-color:red">Blender</div>
            <div class= "circle"style = "background-color:orange">Research</div>
            <div class= "circle"style = "background-color:red">English</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
html,body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }

body {
 background: white;
 border: 1px solid #ff0000;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;/* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;/* Firefox, other Gecko */
 box-sizing: border-box;/* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Thanks! Why is it so important to specify the style for the html and the body? Shouldn't the style for the page either be specified under one or the other?

Comment: you can seperate them.

Comment: let me ask you a question, you make html and body 100% . but because of border we have 2 aditional px at body. you will see scroll bars. how can we remove them?

Comment: decrease the percentage...it isn't very elegant, and it might present other problems later,but it gets rid of the scroll bars.

Comment: Try setting the box-styling: border-box for the element, this will prevent the scrollbars on the element.

Comment: @LearnLanguages96 i've updated answer. `box-sizing` will solve this. Also you can search for `css calc` .

Comment: @CoreyC isn't box-styling only useful for putting boxes side by side? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp It seems like it requires two elements, where I am only dealing with one.

Comment: Sorry, that was suppose to be "box-sizing: border-box". What that does is make the border set within the element, rather than added outside. So lets say you have a 100px element with 5px border on each side, that element would equal 110px wide- with box-sizing:border-box that element would remain 100px. This will prevent your scrollbars on body/html.